# R Shiny Setting the Folder which is opened in fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `fileInput` in `shiny`. Now, what I would like to do is to define the folder which is shown based on the fileInput download button. So, e.g. I would like to make sure that the explorer window opens C:/test/test instead of its default library (which could e.g. be C:/test). So, I would like to specify something like

```
fileInput("PE_TS","",multiple=FALSE,path="C:/test/test)
```

where `path` is the path I would want to be shown in the explorer.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `shinyFiles`
https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles

I haven't tried it myself, but I noticed it has a `root` parameter, so it might do what you want

Comment: shinyFiles is only a replacement in cases where the app is running locally - It cannot access the client file system in standard server/client setups...